# AVPlayerItem Play At Index?

Tags: ios, objective-c, indexing, avplayer, icarousel

I have an ICarousel displaying all of my videos properly though when i press the Play Button it will play the video on the next index instead of the index i am on.

I would like it to play at the index specified, i tried passing the `[sender tag]` as index as well as try a little hack to create another subview with the appropriate playeritem at that index.

Nothing seems to work, what would be the cause of this?!!

Here is my `viewForItemAtIndex`

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
      AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[_videoURLS objectAtIndex:index]] options:nil];

     //Video Player View
     _videoView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, mainViewWidth, 220)];
     _videoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:123/255.0 green:123/255.0 blue:123/255.0 alpha:1.0];
     _videoView.center = CGPointMake(100, 170);//170
     _videoView.tag = 20;
     [view addSubview:_videoView];

    //Play Button
     _playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60.0f, 60.0f)];
     [_playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play-icon-grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [_playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playVideo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
     _playButton.center = CGPointMake(100, 160);
     _playButton.tag = index;
     [view addSubview:_playButton];

      //AV Asset Player
     AVPlayerItem * playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
     _player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
     AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_player];
     playerLayer.frame = _videoView.bounds;
     //        [playerLayer setFrame:_videoView.frame];
     [_videoView.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];
     [_player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];

     return view;
}
```

This will display and even play, though it just wont play the right one focused at the time. 
I have been stuck on this for a couple days now, any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Can you provide code of playVideo: method. Then we can see your problem. Because in - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view metod you initilize assets. I think also you use same code in playVideo: method. One thing this problem is always come? If the iCarousel view is not scrolling

Comment: as mentioned by everyone else, please post code for playVideo method in order to solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting in touch with the person who created iCarousel i was able to find a solution.

simply creating the AVPlayer Layer in selctedItemAtIndex instead of in the main views.
This allows me to use

```
_carousel.currentItemView && _carousel.currentItemAtIndex
```

To assign the Layer to that specific carousel view's sub videoView

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the code with playVideo method.? May be it will be an issue with this method.Check whether the url selected from this method is the same as what we return in the view at index.!!

Comment: as you can see from the code above, the AVPlayer makes use of the video url and they are harcoded into an NSArray of strings to get a better result. At this point i should just be able to say [_player play]; though that doesn't work. @Sudeep george

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd use `- (void)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index;` instead of button if it's possible. Second - you are not reusing views and always creating new(and BTW you are always setting the same tag for view, which may be the reason for playing wrong video), that way performance may suffer.

What I would do:
- Create UIView subclass(interface created either with xib file or programmatically - it's the matter of preferences and/or standarts in your environment), create public method like `- (void)configureWithAsset:(AVURLAsset *)asset` or `- (void)configureWithURL:(NSURL *)url` and pass needed info in this method. In implementation you should init AVPlayer with needed video.
Call this method in `- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view` (you can change UIView to your custom subclass name so you're not required to cast) - like this

```
- (VideoView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(VideoView *)view
{
    if (view == nil) {
        view = [VideoView new]; // you may need to create another initializer
    }
    NSURL *url = get URL here;
    [view configureWithURL:url];
    return view;
}
```

Then when you need to play video, call `[videoView playVideo]` (you'll need to create this too, it should just call play on player object).